# Moving character face to face the mouse, but without moving out of the head.? Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I want to make a game with RPG movement, but it's more like a wave game, with static camera.
I want to move the character's face to make it look like it's looking at the mouse, but I didn't find how. I know how to rotate it but not how to rotate it with the mouse. Here are some images so I can explain better.
[This will be when the mouse is either in 0,0 or outside the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnPoL.png)

[And this is when, for example, the mouse is in the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEtkB.png)

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the coordinates of the mouse position in world space by using [Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html). You could use the coordinates to find the right position for the eyes.

Comment: Yeah I thought about it but I'm so bad at maths that I can't know how.

Comment: You can subtract the vector of the mouse position with the vector of the character position and use the result to find the right position for the eyes.